# Let's get critical: Feb 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Chess Stack Exchange](http://chess.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Caro-Kann variation 1.e4 c6 2.d4 d5 3.Nc3 dxe4 4.Nxe4 Nd7 5.Ng5](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4383/caro-kann-variation-1-e4-c6-2-d4-d5-3-nc3-dxe4-4-nxe4-nd7-5-ng5)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why is castling through and out of check prohibited?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4414/why-is-castling-through-and-out-of-check-prohibited)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Software To Create Chess Videos](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4455/software-to-create-chess-videos)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Is it possible to checkmate with rook and knight against just king?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4412/is-it-possible-to-checkmate-with-rook-and-knight-against-just-king)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to install stockfish on ubuntu?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4353/how-to-install-stockfish-on-ubuntu)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Interactive chess coaching software](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4416/interactive-chess-coaching-software)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [It is important to play e4 or d4 to 'control the center'. Myth or reality?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4431/it-is-important-to-play-e4-or-d4-to-control-the-center-myth-or-reality)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Guidelines for preparation for a Blitz tournament](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4342/guidelines-for-preparation-for-a-blitz-tournament)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Longest path for knight](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4465/longest-path-for-knight)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Where can I download (or buy) a database of Chess960 games?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4424/where-can-i-download-or-buy-a-database-of-chess960-games)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---